# Overlapping Field Issue

Tags: content-editor

We are running into a strange issue with a Sitecore field overlapping in only one of our Sitecore 6.6 environments.

We've verified that the field configuration is correct (and that the same configuration works well in other environments with the same code base).

[image: Strange Overlapping Issue]

There's a div that is insisting on maintaining a 24 pixel height for just this one multilist field.

Has anyone else run into this before?

Comment: Can you specify if this is browser specific? Try in Chrome, FF and IE. Chances are it will work well in IE.

Comment: We did hear phantom reports of it working in an older version of IE, but we were able to reproduce it in all browsers.

Comment: I would test it out on IE9/10 if possible to go with Sitecore 6.5/6.6. Do you know if the install itself is as up to date as possible with all kb fixes? Is there a timeline for an upgrade at least to 7.2?

Comment: We were still seeing it on IE 9 & 10. We are in the process of upgrading to 8.2 now, and the issue seems to be isolated to just that one environment. Luckily that one environment was not Production (this time).

Comment: Very odd indeed. Does this happen with 8.2 on that specific environment as well?

Comment: We aren't that far along in the process yet, but I'll update this if we run into it again in 8.2. I don't think we will, as it seems isolated. We are doing a database refresh into the environment with the issue, and I'll post here with the results. We aren't burning more cycles trying to track down the root cause right now.

Answer (score 2):

Previously I have seen a similar issue, if the core stylesheets are from a different version of Sitecore.

This issue can typically occur, if the core stylesheets are deployed as a part of your solution, and have not been upgraded when upgrading Sitecore.

Try comparing `/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/default/Content Manager.css` between the environments for any differences.